# No data return If search condition of a select query contains only numerals and query on a nVarChar column of a table

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I have windows application to synchronize data of a windows mobile application stored in a SQL Server CE database. I got a few issues on synchronization of mobile connected to windows 7 32bit PC.

On synchronization, windows application will copy the SQL Server CE database from Mobile Device to the PC and do synchronization of data with locally copied database then copy back to the Mobile Device. If the PC which done synchronization is a windows 7 32Bit then I'll get following issues in Windows Mobile Application when working with synchronized database.

If there is a table with `nVarChar` columns and do search query on that column, no data will return if search condition contains numerals with single quotes to indicate value as a string (in following example `strProductID` is a `nVarchar` column)

eg:-

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE strProductID = '2345'
```

But numerals without quotes or alpha with quotes will works fine

eg:-

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE strProductID = 2345
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE strProductID = 'asdasd'
```

Comment: (1) why are you using an NVARCHAR column to store numbers? (2) have you tried properly prefixing your Unicode string literal, e.g. `WHERE strProductID = N'2345'`? (3) why are you using silly data type prefixes?

Comment: Use parameterized queries with the right data types. I have no idea why you would sometimes have single quotes and sometimes wouldn't. Create a parameterized query with a data type that matches the column and stop bothering yourself with these unnecessary (and problem-causing) details.

Comment: Im not storing numbers in that column but which field contain string codes which can contain combination of numeric and alpha. If mobile interface provide facility to search the code and users can do search using just part of the code so the value type in search field can be just numerals. Therefore query will be as SELECT * FROM Products WHERE strProductID LIKE 'asdasd%' and even this will not work if SQL CE database syncronization done in a windows7 32bit machin but syncronized SQL CE databases in XP and Windows7 64bit PCs will works fine with mobile application.

Comment: Did you see my comment about using `N'asdasd'` instead of `'asdasd'`? Can you repro your problem on [SQLfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: I do not use some queries with single quotes and some without quotes I'm using quotes in every query as the field is a NVarchar column but I explained here it will not works if search condition contain just numerals with quotes and I tried it without quotes just to check and it worked and even with quotes query worked if search condition contain alpha string.

Comment: DROP and CREATE the index on that column

Comment: Show us actual, full code of the data query objects, not just the SQL

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron Bertrand has stated in the comment, your queries will work much better if you use Parameters.

How large is the `strProductID` NVARCHAR field? 50? I'm going to assume 50 so I can write your parameterized query:

```
private DataTable Get(string strProductID, string connStr) {
  var table = new DataTable();
  string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE strProductID=@strProductID";
  using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(cmdText, new SqlCeConnection(connStr))) {
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@strProductID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = strProductID;
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    cmd.Connection.Close();
  }
  return table;
}
```

However, Microsoft has admitted that Disconnected Datasets are not very reliable in Windows Mobile devices! See the comments in the [Walkthrough: Creating an Occasionally Connected Smart Device Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488004%28v=vs.90%29).